# Google Website Scraping getting blocked after few requests

Tags: web-services, google-app-engine, google-apps

We are developing a simple application that makes call to one of Google's services (Reverse Image Search http://www.google.com/insidesearch/features/images/searchbyimage.html by uploading images by url/image and getting the entity name for the image). Essentially, we were getting the results page (as html) that Google returned and scraping the results using a simple parser.

We hosted this on Google App Engine and found that after a while Google blocked our app (identified by the IP) and send out a message saying it is to prevent bots from sending requests to its websites. Below is the message I found in the web server's logs:

> This page appears when Google automatically detects requests coming from your computer network which appear to be in violation of the http://www.google.com/policies/terms/">Terms of Service. The block will expire shortly after those requests stop. In the meantime, solving the above CAPTCHA will let you continue to use our services.
> This traffic may have been sent by malicious software, a browser plug-in, or a script that sends automated requests. If you share your network connection, ask your administrator for help — a different computer using the same IP address may be responsible. http://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640">Learn more
> Sometimes you may be asked to solve the CAPTCHA if you are using advanced terms that robots are known to use, or sending requests very quickly.

I wanted to check if there is a way to solve this or any workaround, etc. Since Google doesn't expose any Reverse Image Search API's, we do not see any other way (other than creating a http request and scraping the response) to get the info we want.

Any leads will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in violation of the terms of service, that's that. Any "workaround" would be inappropriate.

This service is exactly the same and has an API you can legitimately use: http://services.tineye.com/TinEyeAPI

> **What is TinEye API?** TinEye is a reverse image search engine. You can
>   submit an image to TinEye to find out where it came from, how it is
>   being used or if modified versions of the image exist. TinEye uses
>   image recognition to perform its searches. The TinEye API allows a
>   user to search the multi billion TinEye image index automatically.